# Can a query string parameter key contain the hyphen (-) char?

Tags: php, http, coldfusion

Hello to everyone who might read this question.

The question is very basic, can a query string parameter key contain the hiphen (-) char?

I have this url
`https://www.example.com/page?uid=83485743jfj4f37gj348&thank-you`

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you tried performing a POST or GET request to a ColdFusion/Lucee server to dump the FORM or URL scope? You'll will need to use array notation (versus dot notation) to programmatically access the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from

https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application-x-www-form-urlencoded-percent-encode-set

you can use the hypen character without any escaping.